# disable ssl-certificate verification when installing with pip

Tags: python, pip, ssl-certificate

I use python for work and often need to install packages using pip but because the IT-department at work is using an https-man-in-the-middle every time i try to install packages while on the internal compagny network it failes with an ssl-certificate verification error.

Until recently I had a colleague (he left) who had found a command to disable the verification which enabled install with pip through the compagny network, it was something like SSL_...-VERIFY.. = FALSE ??? something like that very straight forward, but i don't remember it exactly and i cant seem to find it anywhere on the internet.

I find lots of solutions to the same problem but none of them work for me, here i'm thinking of solutions like '--trusted-host..' etc.

Please does anyone know the command I'm looking for?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. My proxy server injects the company SSL Cert which pip obviously doesnt like. I need a way to access the cert or add it permanently to the python or pip's CA bundle.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get pip working by using **both** the `--trusted-host` flag and also the `--cert` flag to point it to the root certificate for the network.  The certificate would be installed on any workstation subject to SSL MITM so you can export the certificate yourself or ask your IT department for it.

Example command that worked for me:

```
pip3 install ipython --trusted-host pypi.python.org --cert /path/to/cert/root_cert.cer
```